# What is $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus

I was trying to find the derivative of $$\frac{x^2 + 4x + 3}{\sqrt{x}}$$

But my professor told me I didn't need to use the product rule, instead I could just divide straight through since its a monomial. How do I divide $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$ ? Or should I just discount 3 altogether since there is no x value?

Comment: Write it as $3x^{-1/2}$, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that any root can be written as a term with a fractional exponent.  Also remember that powers on the bottom of a fraction can be written in the numerator by making them negative.  Hence, $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$ can be written as $3x^{-1/2}$ (as the comment above states).  From there, use your differentiation rules for powers of variables and you're good!

Answer (score 5):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=x^{-1/2}$, so $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}=3x^{-1/2}$.

Now you can apply the regular differentiation rules.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you simply need to do the derivative of $\frac{3}{\sqrt(x)}$. So that means you just need to do the derivative of $3x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ which if you know how to deal with regular derivatives this shouldn't be much of a challenge.